# CakePHP 3.0 - Login not working

Tags: cakephp, authentication, cakephp-3.0

I've been following the CakePHP 3.0 tutorials (Bookmarker & Blog) regarding the Login/Authentication sections and applying it to my own code, but I can't seem to get it working properly.

I'm able to see all indexes without even being logged in. <s>Logging into the system does not work; the login page just refreshes.</s>

EDIT: Okay, seems like my test users were duds, I made a new user and it can login. However, I still have the issue of non-users being able to see indexes of tables (they can't create any variables in any of the tables apart from User, which has been allowed specifically).

EDIT2: I fixed it by removing the beforeFilter function in AppController.

User Controller:

```php
<?php
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Controller\AppController;
use Cake\Event\Event;

class UsersController extends AppController
{
    public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
    {
        parent::beforeFilter($event);
        $this->Auth->allow(['add', 'logout']);
    }   

    public function login()
    {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $user = $this->Auth->identify();
            if ($user) {
                $this->Auth->setUser($user);
                return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
            }
            $this->Flash->error(__('Incorrect username or password, please try again.'));
        }
    }

    public function logout()
    {   
        $this->Flash->success('You are now logged out.');
        return $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->set('users', $this->Users->find('all'));
    }

    public function view($id)
    {
        $user = $this->Users->get($id);
        $this->set(compact('user'));
    }
}
```

App Controller:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Cake\Controller\Controller;
use Cake\Event\Event;

class AppController extends Controller
{
    public function initialize()
    {
        $this->loadComponent('Flash');
        $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
            'loginRedirect' => [
                'controller' => 'Users',
                'action' => 'index'
            ],
            'logoutRedirect' => [
                'controller' => 'Pages',
                'action' => 'display',
                'home'
            ]
        ]);
    }
}
```

User Table:

```php
<?php
namespace App\Model\Table;

use Cake\ORM\Table;
use Cake\Validation\Validator;

class UsersTable extends Table
{

    public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
        {
        $validator
            ->integer('id')
            ->allowEmpty('id', 'create');

        $validator
            ->requirePresence('username', 'create')
            ->notEmpty('username', 'A username is required');

        $validator
            ->requirePresence('password', 'create')
            ->notEmpty('password', 'A password is required');

        $validator
            ->email('email')
            ->requirePresence('email', 'create')
            ->notEmpty('email', 'An email is required');

        $validator
            ->requirePresence('role', 'create')
            ->notEmpty('role', 'inList', [
                'rule' => ['inList', ['admin', 'artist', 'engineer']],
                'message' => 'Please enter a valid role'
            ]);

        return $validator;
    }
}
```

Comment: Now that you've edited your actual question, please either update the rest of it to include relevant code or close this one and re-ask your new question.

Comment: You have `$this->Auth->allow(['index', 'view', 'display']);` in your AppController, and you call this in UsersController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it by removing the beforeFilter function in AppController.

Answer (score 0):

public function beforeSave(Event $event)
            {
                $entity = $event->data['entity'];

```
            // Make a password for digest auth.
            $entity->digest_hash = DigestAuthenticate::password(
                $entity->username,
                $entity->password,
                env('SERVER_NAME')
            );
            return true;
        }
```